# PHP: If [variable] equals to [true or false] then

Tags: php

I was just trying to figure this out. In my config, I have the variable $_SITE_MAINTENANCE.

This must be either true or false. How do I make it so that if $_SITE_MAINTENANCE is true, the page redirects to maintenance.php and if $_SITE_MAINTENANCE is false, it just shows the page.

Is this doable with PHP?

Kindest regards, Lennert.

Comment: It is doable, and you've figured out what to do. Now you just need to write it down in code.

Comment: Yhea, but I don't know how to do it in code...

Comment: `if ($_SITE_MAINTENANCE == TRUE) { header('Location: maintenance.php'); }` Really, it's such a basic thing that you could have found in 2 minutes by searching in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need to do. If `$_SITE_MAINTENANCE` is set, a browser will be sent to `maintenance.php`.  If not, any code beneath that snippet will just run as expected.

```
if ($_SITE_MAINTENANCE) {
  header('Location: maintenance.php');
}
```

Comment: Thanks JakeGould! This worked out perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
if ($_SITE_MAINTENANCE) {
      header('location: maintenance.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, with basic knowledge about if() and header(). You may prefer a constant or $_ENV-Setting instead of a common variable, to control it centralized.

Your case:

```
if ( $_SITE_MAINTENANCE ) {
    header('Location: http://example.org/full/qualified/url/required');
}
```

Constant example:

```
// somewhere ...

define('MAINTENANCE', true);

// elsewhere

if ( defined('MAINTENANCE') && MAINTENANCE ) {
    header('Location: http://example.org/full/qualified/url/required');
}
```

Environment

on .htaccess

```
SetEnv MAINTENANCE 1
```

on project code

```
if ( isset($_ENV['MAINTENANCE']) && $_ENV['MAINTENANCE'] ) {
    header('Location: http://example.org/full/qualified/url/required');
}
```